# Equivalence Induction and Well-Ordering

Tags: logic, induction, well-orders

I need some help please.  I am trying to get to grips with proving the equivalence between mathematical induction (MI) and well-ordering principle (WOP).  As a theorem, I have

**Principle of mathematical induction.** Let $P(n)$ be a statement about the natural numbers, if it is established that both

1. $P(1)$ is true
2. For every natural number $k$, if $P(k)$ is true, then $P(k+1)$ is also true.

Then $P(n)$ is true for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

From my understanding of the theorem, it means that if both conditions 1 and 2 hold, then $P(n)$ is true for all natural numbers, or $1$ AND $2$ $\implies$ $P(n)$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.  So, to prove MI, I need to assume 1 and 2 to be true, and demonstrate that $P(n)$ is true for all natural numbers.  By using the well-ordering principle and assuming there exists some n such that $P(n)$ is false I arrive at a contradiction - that is fine.

However, proving that WOP $\implies$ MI, I find confusing.  In my mind it looks a bit like

WOP $\implies$ $\Big($($1$ AND $2$) $\implies$ $P(n)$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N})\Big)$.

Must I assume that the WOP is true, assume both 1 and 2 are true, and demonstrate that $P(n)$ is true for all n?  Or must I assume that WOP is true, and first demonstrate that both 1 and 2 hold before showing that it holds for all natural numbers?

Comment: Note that the argument you already have (in the paragraph starting "From my understanding ...") proves the direction WOP${}\Rightarrow{}$MI. (Perhaps the source of your confusion is that you find yourself doing exactly the thing you've already done -- because you have not actually switched direction?) What remains is the direction MI${}\Rightarrow{}$WOP. There you need to assume that induction works and prove that every nonempty set of naturals has a least element.

Comment: To be pendantic, Well Ordering is only equivalent to Induction if you assume every nonzero value has a predecessor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Must I assume that the WOP is true, assume both 1 and 2 are true, and demonstrate that P(n) is true for all n? Or must I assume that WOP is true, and first demonstrate that both 1 and 2 hold before showing that it holds for all natural numbers?

Your first guess is the right one. Remember that when we want to prove a statement of the form $X\implies Y$, we assume $X$ and try to prove $Y$ *(in the context of having assumed $X$)*. So to prove a statement of the form $$A\implies (B\implies C),$$ we "iterate" this process:

- Assume $A$, and try to prove $B\implies C$.
- But to prove $B\implies C$ *(within the context of having assumed $A$)* we assume $B$ and try to prove $C$.

So really this simplifies to

- **Assume $A$ and $B$ and try to prove $C$.**

One way to think about this on a symbolic logic level is to show that $$A\implies (B\implies C)$$ is equivalent to $$(A\mbox{ and }B)\implies C$$ *(incidentally, this has a [set theory/computer science analogue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying))*.

Comment: In his case, WOP is an axiom and it is assumed to be true. he just need to prove that 1 and 2 are true .

Comment: @Salahamam_Fatima No, he needs to *assume* that 1 and 2 are true and then prove the conclusion (that $P$ holds of all natural numbers). (Also, I don't think you're right about WOP being an axiom in his context - I think he's talking about proving "WOP implies MI" over a weak theory of arithmetic, namely one without either WOP or MI, but that's a side issue.)

Comment: He has not to prove the conclusion !

Comment: @Salahamam_Fatima I don't understand what you're saying. To prove "WO implies (if 1 and 2 hold, then P holds for all n)" you have to assume WO *(maybe you have this as an axiom already, in which case it's already been assumed)* and 1 and 2 and then prove "P holds for all n."

Comment: He has not to prove that P hold for all $n$. If he proves 1 and 2 then automatically P holds for all n.

Comment: @Salahamam_Fatima "If he proves 1 and 2 then automatically P holds for all n." - **that's what they're trying to prove from WO**. And to do this, they need to (assume WO and) assume 1 and 2 and prove $\forall n(P(n))$. You're talking about how to *apply* MI, taking for granted that they've already proved it.

Comment: Okay i see now . thanks

Comment: I realise my question is a bit backwards (!), but (A->B)->C = (A and B) -> C is the part I was not sure of and the iterative process makes sense to me.  Thank you.

Comment: @Salahamam_Fatima Your input has also proven insightful.  I get now, that if I assume MI as an axiom, if I can demonstrate 1 and 2 to be true, P will be true automatically :)